# 405 method not allowed error appears at start but then disappear

Tags: jquery, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am working on application having feeds and comments (e.g status and comments). 
when i add a new feed it works fine and new feed gets add. When i start adding comments on the feed, i get

"405 method not allowed".

But when i refresh the page and then start adding comments, comments add successfully. 
Can any one tell me why is it so. 
I am using same jquery/ajax for adding feeds and comments.

Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : loc,
            cache : false,
            data : message,
            crossDomain : true,
                dataType : "json",
    //      dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("feed/comment added");                
                }
            }
        });
```

PS: I am using Spring and Tomcat. and i am using same function for adding feeds and comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the page, your browser makes a HTTP GET request to the server.  However, when you request a comment to be added you are sending a HTTP POST request.  It seems as if the server is configured to only accept GET (and maybe others), but not POST requests.

You could try

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : loc,
        cache : false,
        data : message,
        crossDomain : true,
            dataType : "json",
//      dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("feed/comment added");                
            }
        }
    });
```

Or alternatively, if the server is yours, just configure it to accept POST requests.

EDIT:
Thinking further, there may also be a little more complication involved (based on the fact that it works after a page refresh).  It maybe that something like a HTTP PUT (or HTTP OPTIONS) request is being sent, hence causing the issue.  Ideally, you'd look at the server logs to find out which request is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Steve for reply, my form action is post and it works fine after first refresh. After google search, to me it seems to be due to cross domain policy, is there any way to solve it. I have made changes to tomcat too but not working.